# angularJS - directive not able to get `index` of array value

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am passing the array to `directive` and getting it in directive method. but I am trying to get a `index` of value. but getting as `undefiend`. what is the issue here?

array creation :

```
var dataSize = gridView.baseData.length / viewPorts;
        for( var i = 0; i < dataSize; i++ ){
            gridView.pages[i] = {
                show : i ==0 ? true:false,
                pageData : gridView.baseData.splice( 0, viewPorts )
            };
        }
        return gridView.pages;
```

here is my directive:

```
var dataGridMaker = function( ) {

    return {
        scope: {
            "pages" : "="
        },
        replace: true,
        template : GridTemplate.join(''),
        link: function(  scope, element, attrs ) {
            console.log( scope.pages ); //getting all array values
            console.log( scope.pages[0] ); //undefined-why?
        }
    }

}
```

here is the console:

```
[]0: Object 1: Object 2: Object 3: Object 4: Object 5: Object 6: Object 7: Object 8: Object 9: Objectlength: 10__proto__: Array(0)
dataGridDirective.js:24 undefined
```

Comment: can you show scope.pages ?

Comment: required to post `array` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be an unresolved promise or a scope change (depends on what you are doing in the controller). Try to wrap `console.log( scope.pages[0] );` in a timeout with no delay and see what happens. Something like this:

```
$timeout(function () {
   console.log( scope.pages[0] );
});
```